# Is there a way to make the Function keys act as standard keys with a Logitech K811 keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I changed the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on my Macbook Pro to actually work in the reverse way (so, just hitting the <kbd>F1</kbd> key actually sends the "Function 1" signal, rather than the brightness decrease signal when the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is not pressed, and the brightness decrease signal if the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is pressed). I did this because, as a developer, it's much more useful to me to be able to utilize the function keys than the other (what I consider auxiliary) functions.

However, when I'm at home, I use an external keyboard (a Logitech K811). It's a great keyboard, but it doesn't seem to sense the preference change I made with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. That is, on my macbook keyboard, I don't have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> to activate the function keys, but on my Logitech keyboard, I do.

Is there a way to make the Logitech keyboard also act the way I have it setup in my System Preferences?

Comment: Did you check the settings in Logitech ? and did you try all 3 BT connections ?

Comment: Do you have the Logitech Preferences Manger installed ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I now have the Logitech Preferences Manager installed. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Logitech you need they [Preferences Manger](http://support.logitech.com/product/illuminated-keyboard-for-mac-ipad-iphone) download and installed.

Make sure you pick the right OS X and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS 11 or later, you need to install the “Logi Options+” application, your keyboard will connect automatically, and you need to enable the corresponding option in the settings

Answer (score -1):

In 2019 Logitech utillity to redefine Fn keys is called [SetPoint](https://support.logi.com/hc/ru/articles/360024848993--%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-Bluetooth-Illuminated-Keyboard-K810). There you can redfine all FN button, even f1, f2, f3 button can obtain classic behaviour. Hope this helps.